# Create Directory Using Partial Path

Tags: powershell, wildcard, filepath, create-directory

#### Problem

In PowerShell, is it possible to create a new file directory using a partial path that has wildcards (Ex: `C:\*\SomeFolder\MyBackup`)? If so, how?

#### Details

I am working with PowerShell to create an application, and one part of that application has the user designate a backup directory. This directory could be an exact path, but I am also expecting that wildcards could be used. With that said, I know I can easily use `MD C:\SomePath\` or `New-Item "C:\SomePath\" -FileType Directory` IF the path provided is absolute; however, it fails whenever I try to do this with wild cards.

**Examples**: These all fail when I attempt them

1. `MD "C:\*\MyBackups\AppBackup"`
2. `New-Item "C:\*\MyApp\Backup" -FileType Directory`
3. `$fullPath = "C:\*\MyApp\Backup" | Resolve-Path`
4. `$fullPath = Resolve-Path "C:\*\MyApp\Backup"`
5. `$ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath("C:\*\MyApp\Backup")`

Now, I understand part of the failure is the wildcard itself as the command doesn't understand how to interpret it.

I have researched things like `New-Item`, `Convert-Path`, `Resolve-Path`, and `Split-Path`, but haven't been able to find anything that is related to what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Relative to what?

Comment: A "relative path" means "relative to my current location". `..` means "the parent of the current location". Add ``\`` and another `..` to mean "parent of the parent". Thus if your current location is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14`, the notation `..\..` refers to `C:\Program Files (x86)`.

Comment: Updated base post to clarify better... I meant a "Partial Path" not "Relative Path"

Comment: It will need to know, through some method, of what the * indicates. It can be relative, but that relative location must be captured before you attempt to do a New-Item. Is the * the user input?

Comment: A partial path is a part of a path. What you have there is a path with wildcards.

Comment: If you know the depth of the search may be its easy.
for example `get-childitem \*\*\*` at c:\ would search upto 2 sub folders.
`Get-ChildItem \*\*\*  -Directory   | where {$_.Name -match "Documents"}`

Comment: @Paolis Yes this is meant to come from a user's input. I am trying to account for users that try to store the backup to a specific path either with the exact path OR utilizing wild cards to set it is specific folder without knowing the full path

Comment: @VGSandz I will have to give that a try, as the idea is that I won't know how many levels to parse through, but I may be able to modify that to fit my needs.

Comment: @Brandon my gut reaction is that you should be controlling the input. To simplify your code I would not permit wildcards in what should be a single path. The user input should be a specified folder. Logically a user would not be backing up files to any or all directories, it will be only to a single location.

Comment: @Paolis I can completely agree with this. And it seems that this would be the most viable path to take. The end goal was to provide a way for a user who didn't know the exact path of their backup folder, but knew the general sub folder and wanted to provide that partial path... But I may be over complicating things again

Comment: @Brandon If they don't know the exact path because they forgot the dir they selected initially I added an Edit to my answer to possibly have a solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

`md`, which is an alias for a wrapper function around `New-Item`, expects an exact path. If you want to create a directory based on a wildcard path you need something like this:

```
Get-ChildItem 'C:\*\MyBackups' | ForEach-Object {
    New-Item -Type Directory -Path $_.FullName -Name 'MyBackup' | Out-Null
}
```

Note that wildcards in a path usually cover just one level of hierarchy. If you want to find *any* subfolder `MyBackups` on the C: drive you need an approach like this:

```cs
Get-ChildItem 'C:\' -Filter 'MyBackups' -Directory -Recurse | ForEach-Object {
    New-Item -Type Directory -Path $_.FullName -Name 'MyBackup' | Out-Null
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I was always of the understanding that wildcards could act recursively... So a search of `C:\*\MyBackups` that is actually looking for `C:\Temp\SubFolder\MyBackups` would fail to find this?

In example 2: If we are of the understanding that the path is coming from a User's input and that "MyBackups" doesn't exist, wouldn't this example fail initially? From what I am understanding, this is searching recursively on a fixed point, and then adding an additional sub directory with the same name. I would expect the final directory to be something like: `C:\Temp\SubFolder\MyBackups\MyBackups`

Comment: The 2nd example is looking for existing folders `MyBackups` and creates a subfolder `MyBackup` inside the folders it finds (e.g. `C:\Temp\Subfolder\MyBackups\MyBackup`). If it can't find an existing folder `MyBackups` no backup folder will be created.

Comment: Hmm... Then this example doesn't quite fit my needs; however, this gives me an idea. If it succeeds I'll post it.

Comment: You need some kind of anchor. How would you know where to create the folder otherwise?

Comment: Well I had thought of that too and I was thinking that I could parse the user's input and grab the name of the parent directory and use that as an anchor. But I'm having some trouble getting this to work right

Answer (score 0):

If you'r attempting to take user input and make that represent the *, then you need to represent that in your code. The only area that confuses me is that you have wildcards. I don't think I fully understand what purpose the wildcards serve in your script.

```
$backupTemplate = 'MyBackups\AppBackup'

#This can be a lot of different methods of input, from a Read-Host or what I have below
$dirSelector = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog -Property @{ SelectedPath = Get-Location }
$dirSelector.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
$dirSelector.SelectedPath

$bckupDir = "$($dirSelector.SelectedPath)\$backupTemplate"

#EDIT: You were indicating below you needed to find the parent directory for the 'anchor'. Added this here for that.
$parentDir = (Get-Item $dirSelector.SelectedPath).Parent.FullName

if(-not (Test-Path -Path $bckupDir))
{
    New-Item -Path $bckupDir
}

#Execute your code here on whatever is doing the backup.
```

EDIT/Addition:

If the problem you are running in to is that the User sets their backup directory once and then may not remember where it was, then you should look into storing this variable somewhere that both the user can recall in your cmdlets and your cmdlets can access to utilize.

A very common way to do this is to create a file that holds the settings that the user makes in regards to whatever you are attempting to accomplish.

A nice way to do this is to create a standard object and then export that as an CliXML (or JSON or whatever format you like to work with) like so:

```
$userSettings = New-Object -TypeName psobject
$userSettings | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name User -Value $env:USERNAME
$userSettings | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name LastUpdate -Value $(Get-Date -format u)
$userSettings | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name BackupDirectory -Value $dirSelector.SelectedPath

$userSettings | Export-Clixml -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\psUserProf.xml"

#when you need to get the users backup folder in the future you just import the profile and work from there
$userSettings = Import-Clixml -Path "$env:USERPROFILE\psUserProf.xml"
$userSettings.BackupDirectory
```

Note though that if your users have more than one computer you'll need to facilitate a way for these settings to follow them.

Comment: I see how you were confused. The * itself is not the user input, the path provided is. So I was trying to see if it was possible to allow the user to provide wildcards, and using that wildcard resolve the full path

Comment: @Brandon I added some more details above in an edit.